Electron scattering with photon emission
I only need some reference or literature on how to write all Feynman diagrams with propagators and calculate their amplitudes for Compton scattering of emission of a photon from an electron. It should have only one vertex and be of the type $p \to p+k$ like on this page.
I searched the Internet but didn't find any relevant literature.
Thanks in advance,
Adi

You can find this in section 13.5 in Schwartz’s QFT and the Standard Model textbook. It's a very friendly book.

Thanks you very much!

This is section 5.5 in Peskin and Schroeder. I think it is very well detailed there.

Thank you, Y2H!
